# Is there a dynamic way in BigQuery to select/create columns with pattern?

Tags: select, dynamic, google-bigquery

Not sure how to sure how to best phrase it, but essentially I need ~50 columns x 12 weeks in BigQuery and was hoping there was a way to do it more efficiently using some sort of logic or function.

I can generate the script in Python, but the end output itself is long and unwieldy. Is there a cleaner way to do it within BigQuery itself?

Example code:

```
select id,
  sum(case when first_week_flag then visit else 0 end) as sum_visit_first_week,
  sum(case when second_week_flag then visit else 0 end) as sum_visit_second_week,
  ... for 12 weeks,
  avg(case when first_week_flag then gap else 0 end) as avg_gap_first_week,
  avg(case when second_week_flag then gap else 0 end) as avg_gap_second_week,
  ... for 12 weeks,
  etc. for 50 columns
from table
group by id
```

Potential for simplification:

```
select id,
  sum(case when {WEEK}_flag then visit else 0 end) as sum_visit_{WEEK},
  avg(case when {WEEK}_flag then gap else 0 end) as avg_gap_{WEEk},
  etc. for 50 columns
from table
group by id
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what to search for? Thanks!

Comment: You can use procedural language to build a query dynamically: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language

Comment: Thanks @DamiãoMartins for the information about procedural language. That will come in handy for similar use cases and seems to be the best that can be achieved with BigQuery. It's not quite enough for this use case since I would like to dynamically adjust the variable names as well (not just their values), and it does not seem like BigQuery allows for that.

Comment: Take a look in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, it allow to execute a dynamic generated SQL. So you can use queries or procedure to create another query and then execute it.